# Render a View without loading in the browser - cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, pdf-generation

I am wondering if it is possible to render an action's view without loading in the browser?

I'm using a cakephp component that used mPDF to generate PDF files. The component works well if you load the action and view in a browser but when I want to generate and save the pdf to the drive it doesn't seem to kick in, I'm assuming it's because the view isn't loaded property.

The component I am using is: https://github.com/segy/Mpdf

So basically I have a function called mail_merge which generates a pdf using the mentioned component, I need to call the mail_merge function from another function within the same controller to generate the pdf but without loading in the browser.

Thanks

UPDATE:

I worked out how to set the view as a variable and then write it to the pdf in the function.

ADDED THIS:

```
// RENDER THE VIEW AND SET AS A VARIABLE TO WRITE THE HTML
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------->
$response = $this->render('mail_merge');
$thebody = $response->body();
$this->Mpdf->WriteHTML($thebody);
```

Unfortunately my PDF still won't generate so I guess the issue is something else.

Comment: Could you just hit it via ajax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
$response = $this->render('mail_merge');
$thebody = $response->body();
$this->Mpdf->WriteHTML($thebody);
$this->Mpdf->Output('filename.pdf');
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this is actually how I already have it. I think the issue is to do with the component called in another function for some reason. 6+ hours and still I haven't come up with a solution though.

Comment: What do you mean component called in another function? Are you trying to render from the component?

Comment: Sorry i was mistaken, my original code was a little different, I was using $this->Mpdf->setOutput('filename.pdf'); from the component which wasn't working, now everything is. Thanks for you help!